# Elasticsearch scroll query returning with error

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll

I'm trying to run an elasticsearch query with scrolling. Here's what I'm trying to do, but it is not working. I'm following the instructions here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-request-scroll.html

```
$ curl -u $(whoami) -XPOST 'https://myhost.io/elasticsearch/_msearch?scroll=1m' --data-binary @query.json -H "kbn-version:6.7.1" | jq
Enter host password for user '<first.last>':
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   973    0    96  100   877    321   2933 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3254
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "An internal server error occurred"
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? If I remove the '?scroll=1m', this query works just fine.

Comment: maybe your query and your docs at the given scroll size are causing an out of memory error? What ist the output in the elasticsearch logs?

Comment: I read somewhere (should have saved it), that the '_msearch' API does not support scrolling. I modified my query to use the '_search' API and it seems to return a scroll id, but now I'm getting errors when trying to get the batches once I have that scroll ID

Answer (score 0):

You just need to expand the size of the scroll which is set probably to a smaller size